# Login with linkedin javascript SDK

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Can any one provide the working example of login with linkedin javascript SDK? I tried many demos but it does not work at all.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: 81yvk0mewiwqa6
authorize: true
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    alert("hi");
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email-address").result(displayProfileData).error(onError);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function displayProfileData(data){
    var user = data.values[0];
    document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = '<img src="'+user.pictureUrl+'" />';
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user.firstName+' '+user.lastName;
    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = user.headline;
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = user.emailAddress;
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = user.location.name;
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="'+user.publicProfileUrl+'" target="_blank">Visit profile</a>';
    document.getElementById('profileData').style.display = 'block';
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Destroy the session of linkedin
function logout(){
    IN.User.logout(removeProfileData);
}

// Remove profile data from page
function removeProfileData(){
    document.getElementById('profileData').remove();
}
</script>
</head>
<script type="in/Login"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="onLinkedInLoad();">Linked in</a>
```

I am trying this one also but i am not getting what is the issue.

Also,

```
<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

This line is to display linkedin button but it displays nothing!
Can anyone help?

Comment: can you please share what have you tried so far?

Comment: hey, i edited my question, here is the code which i have tried but it does not work. Have you any idea what is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because the code was not wrapped inside html tag including head and body.

The code which works is here:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
        
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
     
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }
    
    
    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
    function getProfileData() {
     
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email-address").result(displayProfileData).error(onError);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function displayProfileData(data){
        var user = data.values[0];
        alert(user.emailAddress);
        alert(user.pictureUrl);
        alert(user.lastName);
        alert(user.headline);
        alert(user.location.name);
        alert(user.publicProfileUrl);
       
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
    // Destroy the session of linkedin
    function logout(){
        IN.User.logout(removeProfileData);
    }
    
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <script type="in/Login"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```